# Is it a good idea to use create_future asyncio?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-asyncio

Documentation says:
Normally there is no need to create Future objects at the application level code.
But so often we can see the following code (simple RPC rabbitmq client):

```py
import asyncio
import uuid
from aio_pika import connect, IncomingMessage, Message


class FibonacciRpcClient:
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.connection = None
        self.channel = None
        self.callback_queue = None
        self.futures = {}
        self.loop = loop

    async def connect(self):
        self.connection = await connect(
            "amqp://guest:guest@localhost/", loop=loop
        )
        self.channel = await self.connection.channel()
        self.callback_queue = await self.channel.declare_queue(exclusive=True)
        await self.callback_queue.consume(self.on_response)

        return self

    def on_response(self, message: IncomingMessage):
        future = self.futures.pop(message.correlation_id)
        future.set_result(message.body)

    async def call(self, n):
        correlation_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        future = self.loop.create_future()

        self.futures[correlation_id] = future

        await self.channel.default_exchange.publish(
            Message(
                str(n).encode(),
                content_type="text/plain",
                correlation_id=correlation_id,
                reply_to=self.callback_queue.name,
            ),
            routing_key="rpc_queue",
        )

        return int(await future)


async def main(loop):
    fibonacci_rpc = await FibonacciRpcClient(loop).connect()
    print(" [x] Requesting fib(30)")
    response = await fibonacci_rpc.call(30)
    print(" [.] Got %r" % response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Is it a good idea to use loop.create_future() in the case above? Is it the best practice to use that?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, there is no need to call `create_future`. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html) recommend to keep this function out of any user-facing APIs.

But in the example you have shared, the method is used to properly fetch the result of a synchronous by all other means `on_response` operation.

Futures could/should be used when writing asynchronous wrappers over other libraries, when there is a need to combine synchronous interfaces with `async/await`.